# I keep getting an "illegal start of expression" error on my code

Tags: java

I've just recently started using methods in java, and I keep encountering this error on a project that I am working on.
The error is as follows:

```
Main.java:32: error: illegal start of expression
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    ^
1 error
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static int speedCheck(boolean birthday, int speed)
    {
        int hold = 0;
        if (birthday == true){
            if (speed < 65){
                hold = 0;
            }
            else if ((speed >= 66) && (speed <= 85)){
                hold = 1;
            }
            else{
                hold = 2;
            }
        if (birthday == false){
            if (speed < 60){
                hold = 0;
            }
            else if ((speed >= 61) && (speed <= 80)){
                hold = 1;
            }
            else{
                hold = 2;
            }
        return hold;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        boolean birthday = false;
        int speed = (int)(Math.random()*(100-50+1)+50);
        System.out.print("You have been driving a little too fast, and a police officer has pulled you over.");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Your speed is " + (speed) + " miles per hour.");
        System.out.print("Is it your birthday? Answer Yes or No.\n");
        char birthdayCheck = input.nextChar();
        if (birthdayCheck == "Yes")
            birthday = true;
        else if (birthdayCheck == "No")
            birthday = false;
        else
            System.out.print("Invalid input.");
        speedCheck(birthday, speed);
        if (hold == 0)
            System.out.print("You have not been issued a ticket.");
        else if (hold == 1)
            System.out.print("You have been issued a small ticket.");
        else if (hold == 2)
            System.out.print("You have been issued a big ticket.");
    }
}
```

There might be some more issues in my code that I haven't gotten to, as I haven't been able to successfully execute it yet. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have omitted the closing braces from some of the `if` blocks in the preceding method.

Comment: @JohnBollinger right , and also method must return an int if both `if` fails

Comment: I don't believe that Scanner has a nextChar() method, and use Strimg.equals() to compare String's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make these changes**

```
public static int speedCheck(boolean birthday, int speed)
{
    int hold = 0;
    if (birthday == true){
        if (speed < 65){
            hold = 0;
        }
        else if ((speed >= 66) && (speed <= 85)){
            hold = 1;
        }
        else{
            hold = 2;
        }
    return hold;  // added this because method must return int 
    }            // i added this to close the above if block
    else{ //i added else because if birthday is not true it is definitely false you dont have to check that{
        if (speed < 60){
            hold = 0;
        }
        else if ((speed >= 61) && (speed <= 80)){
            hold = 1;
        }
        else{
            hold = 2;
        }
    return hold;
 } // i added this to close above if block
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer questions that ought to be closed, instead.  This one is a clear case for closure on account of the problem resulting from a typographical error.